# Я добавил ссылку в мой код, но он теперь не показывает задний фон

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  width: calc (100% - 20%);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

img {
  width: 9.8%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  float: none;
}

#aside {
  width: 270px;
  height: 425px;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-top: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#article {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  border: 0px solid #FAEEDD;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 300px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#footer {
  width: calc (100% - 20%);
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  margin-top: 372px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/learningenglish.jpg" alt="Learningenglish" title="Learningenglish" /></a>
</div>

<div id="aside"><br/> Present simple
  <hr /> Past simple
  <hr /> Present continuous
  <hr /> Past continuous
  <hr /> Present perfect
  <hr /> Past perfect
  <hr /> Can, Could
  <hr /> Will, would
  <hr /> Reading
</div>

<div id="article">
  <pre>  On this site you can find:
     
     Basic grammar English rules (you can learn 
     the rules that are easy to understand and easy to learn).
     
     Exercises in English (you can do any exercises for present,
     past and future).
     
     Tests reading (if you want to do tests on READING you don't
     need pay for it, it’s all for free).</pre>
</div>

<div id="footer">Privacy policy © 2018</div>
```

[image: Картинки до того, как я вставил ссылку и после неё]
(если что это два изображения я их соединил).

Comment: Удалите свой предыдущий вопрос, зачем тут дубликаты, тем более предыдущий низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: неполный код, приведите весь код, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. в теккущем виде проблема не наблюдается

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в начале определено

```
* {
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

те если напрямую не указать тегу  background-color, то он будет #FAEEDD. Скорее всего вы в этом видите проблему...
Попробуйте сделать так

```
*{
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
}
html{
      background-color: #FAEEDD;
}
```

Может быть это решит вашу проблему) Ну или я не правильно понял, то что у вас не так